# opsworks - how to change php version of the instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I've built a Stack easily and added my PHP App,

So, now I want to change server php version from 5.3 (default) to 5.6. Is this possible?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to look at creating a custom Cookbook to set this up - make sure you are getting the right packages installed for PHP and that will control the version of PHP you are using - If the packages for the requested version are not available you must make your cookbook download the PHP binary install or get it install a repo with the version of PHP you are looking for.

HTHs

Thanks,
//P